# How do I delete photos from my iPhone without also deleting them from my Mac (both are connected to iCloud)

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, photos.app, macos

I currently have about 7k-8k photos and videos stored on my Mac.

Recently, I purchased 200 GB iCloud plan so I can have access to all my photos and videos on my iPhone.  I dragged my Photos library on my Mac into iCloud.

Now, I do not want all of the photos and videos and I want to delete some of them. I don't know how to delete several photos and videos from my iPhone without them also being deleted from my Mac. I thought about disconnecting my Mac from iCloud, but then began wondering as to whether or not it would take all the photos back as well. So what should I do?

**How do I delete photos and videos from my iPhone without them also being deleted from my Mac?**

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way to do this, can you explain the reason why you want to delete them? If it’s storage, you can “Optimize iPhone Storage” in Settings - Photos. If it’s organization, you could create albums.